# Send email to only certain Users, Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having trouble sending an email blast to only certain users who have a boolean set to true and to not send the email to those users who have it set to false.

In my app I have Fans following Artists through Artists Relationships. Inside my ArtistRelationship model I have a boolean that fans can set to true or false based on if they want email blasts from Artists or not when the Artist makes a post.

So far, I have this:

**artist.rb**

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord

  def self.fan_post_email
    Artist.inlcudes(:fans).find_each do |fan|
      fan.includes(:artist_relationships).where(:post_email => true).find_each do |fan|
        FanMailer.post_email(fan).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class Artists::PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @artist = current_artist
    @post = @artist.artist_posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to artist_path(@artist)
      @artist.fan_post_email
    else
      render 'new'
      flash.now[:alert] = "You've failed!"
    end
  end

end
```

I'm having trouble getting the `fan_post_email` method to work. I'm not entirely sure how to find the Fans that have the boolean set to true in the ArtistRelationship model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to send mails to fans of a particular artist. Therefore you call

```
@artist.fan_post_email
```

That is you call a method on an *instance* of the Artist class. Instance methods are not defined with a `self.[METHOD_NAME]`. Doing so defines *class* methods (if you where to call e.g. `Artist.foo`).

First part then is to remove the `self.` part, second is adapting the scope. The complete method should look like this:

```
def fan_post_email
  artists_relationships
    .includes(:fan)
    .where(post_email: true)
    .find_each do |relationship|
      FanMailer.post_email(relationship.fan).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

Let's walk through this method.

We need to get all fans in order to send mails to them. This can be done by using the `artist_relationships` association. But as we only want to have those fans having checked the e-mail flag, we limit those by the `where` statement.

The resulting SQL condition will give us all such relationships. But we do it in batches (`find_each`) in order to not have to load all of the records into memory upfront.

The block provided to `find_each` is yielded with an artists_relationships instance. But we need the fan instances and not the artists_relationships instances to send the mail in our block and thus call `post_email` with the fan instance associated with the relationship.  In order to avoid N+1 queries (a query for the fan record of every artists_relationships record one by one) there, we eager load the fan association on the artists_relationships.

---

**Unrelated to the question**

The usage of that method within the normal request/response cycle of a user's request will probably slow down the application quite a lot. If an artists has many fans, the application will send an e-mail to every one of them before rendering the response for the user. If it is a popular artist, I can easily imagine this taking minutes.

There is a counterpart to `deliver_now` which is `deliver_later` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later). Jobs, like sending an e-mail, can be queued and resolved independent from the request/response cycle. It will require setting up a worker like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) but the increase in performance is definitely worth it.

If the queueing mechanism is set up, it probably makes sense to move the call to `fan_post_email` there as well as the method itself might also take some time.

Additionally, it might make sense to send e-mail as *BCC* which would allow you to send one e-mail to multiple fans at the same time.